# Get every nth element of multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 10 dataframes with an identitcal structure all containing 10000 records. I want to create a matrix containing every 1000th record of all the different dataframes.

So my dataset is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('10000_0.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('10000_1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('10000_2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('10000_3.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('10000_4.csv')
df5 = pd.read_csv('10000_5.csv')
df6 = pd.read_csv('10000_6.csv')
df7 = pd.read_csv('10000_7.csv')
df8 = pd.read_csv('10000_8.csv')
df9 = pd.read_csv('10000_9.csv')
```

Now I want to create an array where [] the first elements is a list of `[df['name'][1000], df1['name'][1000], ..., df9['name'][1000]]`, is it possible to construct this efficiently in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
files = ['10000_{}.csv'.format(x) for x in range(10)]

#list of all DataFrames
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]

#list of one row DataFrame 
L = [x.iloc[[1000]] for x in dfs]
#list of Series
L = [x.iloc[1000] for x in dfs]

#final DataFrame
df1 = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True)
```

Another solution if need only one row:

```
files = ['10000_{}.csv'.format(x) for x in range(10)]

#list of all DataFrames
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=(1, 1000), nrows=1) for f in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas *tail*:

```
arr = []

fnames = ['10000_0.csv',...]

for fname in fnames:
    arr.append(pd.read_csv(fname).tail(1)['name'].values[0])
```